# get the document id after creation in react with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I'm creating an object with firebase to display it in the screen, but after the creation I will need its id in another page to show the object with more details (path example: /object/:id), so when I click the object, I need to take its id and send through the link to another page, and once I'm in the page I will query the id on the link to get the object like that:

```
query(collection(db, "objects"), where("objectId", "==", x))
```

and this is how im creating the object

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // checks if user is logged in
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if(user) {
                addDoc(collection(db, "objects"), {
                name: "my object",
                description: "a nice object",
                owner: user.uid,
                // objectId: x
            }).then((docRef) => {
                docRef.id // I need this to be in the objectId property
            })
        }})
    }}>
```

I would like to know if this is a good approach to this problem, since I will need this id later on the project I thought this was the best way to do it